# Inconsist threads initiated v.s. Scheduled

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have below code to test the concurrency. at the end of the code, I've got the totalCall=29470 and certifiteCount=29470

```
    const int threads = 30000;
    var certificateLists = new List<X509Certificate2>();
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    int totalCall = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            certificateLists.Add(CertificateHelper.ClientPersonalCertificate);
            totalCall++;
        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2Last = null;
    Assert.AreEqual(threads, totalCall);
    Assert.AreEqual(threads, certificateLists.Count);
```

Comment: Consider using some form of locking around your task actions, especially the increment e.g `Interlocked.Increment`

Comment: Why are you using multi threading here?

Comment: Rather than 30k tasks why not just use a `Parallel.ForEach`? That will manage the number of tasks more efficiently.

Comment: I was intentially creating more threads as Parallel.Foreach will be more "efficient" to give me less threads :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to increment `totalCall` is not thread safe. You need to place a lock around that variable, or increment in a thread safe way. Try either of the following:

```
const int threads = 30000;
var certificateLists = new List<X509Certificate2>();
var taskList = new List<Task>();
int totalCall = 0;
obj incrementLock = new object();
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        certificateLists.Add(CertificateHelper.ClientPersonalCertificate);
        lock(incrementLock) {
            totalCall++;
        }
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2Last = null;
Assert.AreEqual(threads, totalCall);
Assert.AreEqual(threads, certificateLists.Count);
```

or use [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure the increment is threadsafe (`interlocked.increment` makes sure the increment is done as one atomic transaction)

```
const int threads = 30000;
var certificateLists = new List<X509Certificate2>();
var taskList = new List<Task>();
int totalCall = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        certificateLists.Add(CertificateHelper.ClientPersonalCertificate);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref totalCall);
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2Last = null;
Assert.AreEqual(threads, totalCall);
Assert.AreEqual(threads, certificateLists.Count);
```

Edit: As pointed out by CodesInChaos, adding to a list is not a thread safe action, so a better idea would be to use ConcurrentBag:

```
const int threads = 30000;
var certificateLists = new ConcurrentBag<X509Certificate2>();
var taskList = new List<Task>();
int totalCall = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        certificateLists.Add(CertificateHelper.ClientPersonalCertificate);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref totalCall);
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2Last = null;
Assert.AreEqual(threads, totalCall);
Assert.AreEqual(threads, certificateLists.Count);
```

Comment: @CodesInChaos good point, however in this case I think the list is being added to synchronously, since the `List.Add` and the `Task.Factory.StartNew` is still on the original thread, only anything inside the lambda is running on a different thread

Comment: He's talking about `certificateLists` which is inside the lambda.